# How to pass context to a child widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a statefull widget `W1` which calls a stateless widget `W2`.

`W2` has `onTap` functionality. I want to show an alert dialog in `W2's onTap()`.

```
onTap:() {Alert(context: context, title:'Hi');},
```

I dont get any error, but no alert is shown on tap. I tried passing context as a parameter to `W2` but I still dont see any dialog box. 
What is the right way to show a dialog box from `W2`?
I am using rflutter_alert package [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert)

Thanks

Comment: `Alert` is just an `Widget`(a class). You just called an constructor to create an instance of `Alert`. So you have to pass this instance to a function named `showDialog` to actually render the widget.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `.show()` in end solved it.

```
onTap:() {Alert(context: context, title:'Hi').show();}
```

Its clearly documented in rflutter_alert package, but I somehow missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `Alert(context: context, title:'Hi');` with `showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => Alert(context: context, title:'Hi'));`

Here is the cookbook sample:

```
Future<void> _neverSatisfied() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
              Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Regret'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Anyway, for your question about how to pass `context`, If you are creating a `Stateless` or `Stateful` widget you dont need to pass the `context`, you can get it from `build(BuildContext context) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context in the function call in onTap:

```
onTap:(context) {Alert(context: context, title:'Hi');},
```